# STL style function to find the middle of an STL container

Tags: c++

I ' m a  newcomer in C++ and I kindly request for help  to resolve an issue.

I'm writing a simple  STL style function , that should return the middle element of sequence (vector, list etc)

Here is my function, I try  to use the concept of  iterator

```
template <class It, class T> It  middle(It first, It last) 
{

    while(first!=last){
        ++first;
        --last;
    }
    return first;
}
```

here  is  my main, trying to call middle for a vector of ints (I've omitted includes)

```
int main() {
    vector<int>vi;
    int x;
    cout<<"Enter vector elemets...";
    while (cin>>x)
    vi.push_back(x);
    cout<<endl;
    cin.clear();
    cout<<"the vector is:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<vi.size();++i)
    cout<<vi[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    vector<int>::iterator first=vi.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator last=vi.end();
    vector<int>::iterator ii=middle(first,last);
    cout<<"The middle element of the vector is: "<<*ii<<endl;
}
```

When compiling with g++ I get the following error:

```
myex21-7.cpp:79: error: no matching function for call to ‘middle(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&)’
```

Could somebody give me some tips to resolve it?
Thanks for any help in advanced
snek

Comment: Just drop the second template parameter in `middle`. It is not needed. Also, have a look at [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
auto middle = container.begin();
std::advance(middle, container.size()/2);
```

If you have C++11 available, `std::next` lets you do the same in one line instead of two.

Also note that in the case of a container that supports random access iterators (e.g., `std::vector`or `std::deque`) this will be relatively efficient (constant complexity instead of linear complexity).

Comment: Simple and efficient, I'm just curious. Will this be O(n^2) on std::lists? I recall .size() being O(n) and since list::iterators can (afaik) only move one node at a time, that would make it O(n^2) ?

Comment: @Borgleader that would make it O(n).

Comment: This doesn't work on raw C arrays.  Write a `std::size_t size( Container const& c )` and it can be made to work.  :)

Answer (score 6):

Unless this is an exercise, it might be simpler to implement something in terms of [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next). Ignoring for now the special case of containers with an even number of elements, you could use something like this:

```
std::vector<SomeType> v = ....;
auto mid = std::next(v.begin(), v.size()/2);
```

As for the problem with your code, your `middle` function template has two parameters:

```
template <class It, class T> It  middle(It first, It last) { .... }
```

But there is no way for the second parameter to be deduced from the function arguments. Since the parameter is not needed anyway, you can simply remove it:

```
template <class It> It  middle(It first, It last) { .... }
```

Answer (score 6):

The other answers here are interesting, but they require access to the container itself. To be truly STL style, you should work with iterator ranges. Here's a solution that does the efficient thing for random access iterators, but also works for forward iterators

```
// http://ideone.com/1MqtuG

#include <iterator>

template <typename ForwardIt>
ForwardIt DoMidpoint(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, std::forward_iterator_tag)
{
    ForwardIt result = first;

    // Try to increment the range by 2
    bool sawOne = false;
    // EDIT: Note improvements to this loop in the comments

    while(first != last)
    {
        ++first;
        if (sawOne)
        {
            // If that succeeded, increment the result by 1
            ++result;
            sawOne = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sawOne = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

template <typename RandomAccessIt>
RandomAccessIt DoMidpoint(RandomAccessIt first, RandomAccessIt last, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    return first + (last - first)/2;
}

template <typename ForwardIt>
ForwardIt midpoint(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    return DoMidpoint(first, last, typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::iterator_category());
}
```

Comment: `template<class It> It midpoint( It begin, It end ) { return std::advance( begin, std::distance(begin, end)/2 ); }` seems shorter.  It does mean that on non-random access iterators, we go over each location 1.5 times.  Your loop might be improved to `while(first!=last){++first; if (first==last) break; ++first; ++result; };`, which folds the paired iterations of your loop into one body.

Comment: @Yakk: `std::advance` returns `void`. You could instead `return std::next(begin, std::distance(begin, end) / 2);`

Comment: @Yakk: I suppose the loop solution also goes over the range 1.5 times because `first` and `result` are incremented separately. That loop looks better too -- not going to change the answer though because I don't want to do another ideone example :)

Comment: @Blastfurnace sorry, I got `next` and `advance` mixed up.

Comment: @BillyONeal However, the real issue is that while C++03-style algorithms are iterator based, there is every reason to believe that C++1z-style algorithms will be container/ranged based.  Getting ahead of the curve and writing such container/range based algorithms isn't a bad thing!

Comment: @Yakk: I don't think so. First, I don't believe range got voted in to the C++14, and, second iterators are strictly more powerful than ranges without generalized ranges. (That is, it is easy to build a container solution in terms of an iterator solution, but not vice versa)

Comment: @billyoneal 1z, not 1y or 14.  Concepts lite is a sensible prequisite for container/range based algorithms, and they really do reduce repitition and eliminate common errors.  The awkwardness of sort-unique-erase in iterators (and the ease of leaving off an end in the erase!), compared to the equivalent container based, is pretty compelling.  Pre concepts-lite, describing container properties is overly awkward, so the standard should wait for that and do it right.

Comment: @Yakk: Even if there are overloads or ways to pass containers, you still need ways to pass iterators for cases where you don't want to operate on the whole container.

Comment: @Yakk: if you're using ranges throughout your program (with the support of a range library like Boost.Range) then it's worth getting ahead of the curve. If your project uses the style of existing standard algorithms, then writing one in a different style is just creating a nuisance, because some caller will want to call it who has an iterator pair, not a range. It will then be on them to integrate a suitable adaptor (again, such as Boost.Range). Writing container-based algorithms is just wrong.

Comment: @stevejessop turning an iterator pair into a range is not what I would call burdensome at compile, write, read or run time.  I find the result easier to read, especially with multiple iterator pair algorithms, as I no longer have to keep a parity count in my head...  The only caution I have is that such patterns are going to get better and better, so if you wait and write them in 5 years the code will be better than if you write them today: but they are already better than iterator based algorithms, and the perfect is the enemy of the good.

Comment: @Yakk: turning it into a range is only easy if you have support of a library providing a range. Given that there is no such library in the standard, I'm not going to use something like that in my "Joe User" answers here. Not everyone in the world can use Boost.

Comment: @BillyONeal We don't need perfect ranges.  `template<typename Iterator> struct range { Iterator m_begin; Iterator m_end; }; template<typename Iterator> range<Iterator> make_range( Iterator begin, Iterator end ) { return {begin, end}; } template<typename Iterator> Iterator begin( range<Iterator> r ) { return r.m_begin; } template<typename Iterator> Iterator end( range<Iterator> r ) { return r.m_end; }` is good enough, if far from perfect.  I did omit `make_range<Container>`, which is another ~100 characters, to leave room for non-code words in this comment.

Answer (score 2):

There are several kinds of iterators in STL, vector features random access ones, which means that you can get iterator to middle element by

```
auto middle = v.begin() + v.size()/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is one additional way:

Assuming `first` and `last` are iterators to container's `begin()` and `end()`, then:

```
Iterator middle = first;
std::advance( middle, std::distance( first, last ) / 2 );
```